# при сохранении в txt файл - два пробела перед записываемой информацией

Tags: python

```
имя = 'test'
class Save:
    def name(имя):
        Save.help(имя)
        f = open('sp/{}.txt'.format(имя), 'r+')
        a = f.read()
        #a = '  15'
        a = str(a)
        a = a.replace('    ', '').replace('  ', '').replace(' ', '')
        try:
            a = int(a)
        except ValueError:
            print('только числа работают')
            #print(a)
        print(a)
        a += 1
        f.truncate(0)
        a = str(a)
        a = a.replace('    ', '').replace('  ', '').replace(' ', '')
        print(a)
        f.write(a)
        f.close()

    def help(имя):
        f = open('sp/{}.txt'.format(имя), 'r+')
        c = f.read()
        c = c.replace('  ', '')
        f.truncate(0)
        f.write(c)
        f.close()

    def main(имя):
        имя = имя
        Save.name(имя)
#нужны переменные: имя
Save.main(имя)
input()
```

Comment: Давай поподробнее. Кроме того, удали ненужное из кода и измени его так, чтобы любой мог скопировать и запустить без правок. Сейчас это невозможно.

Comment: что должен делать код  `a = a.replace('    ', '').replace('  ', '').replace(' ', '')`?

Comment: @VasylKolomiets Пробелы удалять, скорее всего.

Comment: @Эникейщик да, по идее то он должен удалять, но ничего не работает

Comment: этот код даже не запуститься. На первой же строке `SyntaxError`

Answer (score 0):

хоть и сделанно криво, но оно работает

```
a = a.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').replace("x00", '').replace(',','').replace('\\', '').replace("'", '').replace(' ', '')
```

Comment: красава) сам задал вопрос, сам же и ответил

Comment: Какую проблему решает этот код?

Comment: Ваш ответ имеет несколько больший уровень недоступности к пониманию чем Ваш вопрос. Последний, ктому же, не имеет признаков вопроса впринципе, а таковым только именуется так как создан в форме для создания вопросов. Впрочем как и ответ.